iText Migration from 7.0.4 to 7.2.5 spacing issue
I am trying to migrate iText from 7.0.4 to 7.2.5. There were few breaking change in terms of package that I fixed.
The main issue I am now running into is the html to PDF is adding padding / line spacing . This is major blocker since the PDF (letters) to be out of alignment and cannot be printed as per previous spec.
Anyone that has run into this issue before ? I can confirm that the html are the same and the output with change of jars are causing this issue.
   private void createPdf(String src, String dest, String resources) throws Exception
    {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        Document doc = null;
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = null;
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;

        try
        {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(SecurityUtil.checkFileName(dest));

            WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
            // Add metadata
            writerProperties.addXmpMetadata();
            writerProperties.setFullCompressionMode(true);

            pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);
            pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
            doc.setMargins(50, 50, 100, 50);

            pdfDoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
            // Set the document to be tagged
            pdfDoc.setTagged();
            pdfDoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));

            // Set meta tags
            PdfDocumentInfo pdfMetaData = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
            pdfMetaData.setAuthor("");
            pdfMetaData.addCreationDate();
            pdfMetaData.getProducer();
            pdfMetaData.setCreator("");
            pdfMetaData.setKeywords("letter, accessibility");
            pdfMetaData.setSubject("PDF accessibility");
            // Title is derived from html

            // pdf conversion
            ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
            FontProvider fp = new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true);

            LOGSERVICE.logInfo("Font resource Folder:" + resources);

            if (!StringUtil.isEmptyAfterTrim(resources))
            {
                fp.addDirectory(resources);
            }

            props.setFontProvider(fp);
            props.setBaseUri(resources);
            // Setup custom tagworker factory for better tagging of headers
            DefaultTagWorkerFactory tagWorkerFactory = new AccessibilityTagWorkerFactory();
            props.setTagWorkerFactory(tagWorkerFactory);
            
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(SecurityUtil.checkFileName(src));
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(inputStream, pdfDoc, props);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (doc != null)
                doc.close();
            if (pdfDoc != null)
                pdfDoc.close();
            if (pdfWriter != null)
                pdfWriter.close();
            if (outputStream != null)
                SecurityUtil.safeClose(outputStream);
            if (inputStream != null)
                SecurityUtil.safeClose(inputStream);
        }
    }

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

migration to 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

I add the following line. It seems the default font in 7.2.5 shows as font-family=times and in 7.0.4 its font-family=helvetica.
public class AccessibilityTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {

@Override
public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
    System.out.println(tag.name() + "|" + tag.getStyles() + "|" + tag.getAdditionalHtmlStyles());

Source code compare:
1. Font changed 
itext-pdfhtml-java-4.0.5\src\main\java\com\itextpdf\html2pdf\resolver\font\DefaultFontProvider.java
private static final String DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY = "Times";

    

HTML sample
<html><body><p><img src="IMAGE BASE64" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">April 29, 2024</span></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:750px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">TEXT<br>TEXT 2<br>TEXT 3</span></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:800px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:200px"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif"><strong>TEXT:<br />
            TEXT:</strong></span></span></td>
            <td><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">12348167<br />
            7817</span></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif"></span></span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis.</span></span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif"><strong><u>TEXT:</u></strong></span></span></p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="AH-row:ItemsUnderReview" style="height:40px; width:594px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif"><strong>&nbsp;TEXT</strong></span></span></td>
            <td style="width:300px"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif"><strong>&nbsp;TEXT</strong></span></span></td>
            <td><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif"><strong>&nbsp;TEXT</strong></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:15px; vertical-align:top; white-space:nowrap; width:180px"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">&nbsp;03/11/2024</span></span></td>
            <td style="height:15px; vertical-align:top; white-space:nowrap; width:200px"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">TEXT</span></span></span></span></td>
            <td style="height:15px; vertical-align:top; white-space:nowrap; width:260px"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Times New Roman,Times,serif">&nbsp;$TEXT</span></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body></html>




Your may want to illustrate the actual issue a bit: for which input html do you expect which output PDF but instead retrieve which output?

I can see a note in https://itextpdf.com/blog/itext-news-technical-notes/new-chapter-html-pdf-conversion-itext-pdfhtml-300 - but the link is not available :( .. A significant difference for pdfHTML 3.0 is the improved line height calculation, which means this is a breaking change.

this is the correct URL, from the one @Ravi. Indeed, with version 3.x we've changed how line-height gets calculated, and that was one of the reasons to move the major version up.

(the example you're looking for is back on the release page)

Thanks @AndréLemos , I found the example , but it seems there was also a breaking change 1.0.1 to version 2 .. so the code fix did not have much impact. let me review if something else can be found in release notes.

It looks like the updates of the pdfHTML module included breaking changes (which is ok for updates incrementing the major version) and you essentially will have to adapt your HTML inputs. @AndréLemos Maybe iText/Apryse should consider keeping old module behaviors as alternative implementations, at least as long as the major version of the lead product, itextpdf itself, doesn't change.

What we found was pdfHTML 3.0 has workaround to keep 2.0 behaviour. I could not find any release notes for pdfHTML 1.0 to 2.0 that documents a breaking change. Since we do PDF letter , the impact on regression testing is very large efforts to ensure the letter fit envelope size requirements :(
